# Populate link using a form

Tags: php

How do I create a form so that when a user enters details in the text area - that text goes in is placed into the middle of a link when the submit button opens that link.

eg. http://www.mysite.com/hellojohn123hi

Where 123 are placed in the link using a form.

Comment: Have you written the form? Any PHP to go with it?

Comment: i have been searching for answers but an't find any

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I guess i should use GET rather than POSt - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a bit of javascript to place the input(from textarea) into the link of the submit button. and then use, POST. [tutorial to document.ready() in jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Comment: do u know what that javascript should be -thanks

Comment: if you could show the form markup, i can help you.